# Python module 'gi' not found on Arch

Tags: arch-linux, python, python3

I'd like to run a code that uses the gi-module. I'm not quite sure why it's not able to find the module.

The `python-gobject` is installed and used by other programs. I already reinstalled `python-gobject`, but it's still giving the same problem.

The error I get is:

`Dependency missing: python-gobject No module named 'gi'`

I'm using Python 3.7.3 on an Arch Linux System.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you use a python version from the AUR? I guess, you have to create the python37-gobject package. It doesn't exist in the AUR.
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Python#Old_versions

Comment: Thanks for the Answer. I forgot that I installed python via AUR.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install `PyGObject` with `python -m pip install PyGObject`. Brace yourself, problem related to `cairo` library missng are coming!

Comment: Needed to run `sudo apt install libgirepository1.0-dev` on Ubuntu and Python 3.9, then the install PyGObject was successful in PyCharm and now `playsound` works (slightly different problem needed the same solution)